# Проблема с кодировкой при отправке письма с сайта

Tags: php

Второй день, не могу понять, что не так с кодом. Проблема отображения письма, отправленного с сайта есть, как в Яндексе, так и в мэил.ру, только по разному отображается.
Вот код обработчика:

```js
<?php
  header('Content-type: text/plain; charset=UTF-8');

  $mail    = "direct-free@yandex.ru";
  $subject = iconv('UTF-8', 'cp1251', "Моба: письмо отправленное с сайта");
  $header  = "Content-type: text/plain; charset=\"UTF-8\"";
  $header .= "From: " . $mail;
  $header .= "Subject: " . $subject;
  $header .= "Content-type: text/plain; charset=\"UTF-8\"";
  $message =
    iconv('UTF-8', 'cp1251', "Имя: ") . $_REQUEST['Name'] .
    iconv('UTF-8', 'cp1251', "\nПочта: ") . $_REQUEST['Email'] .
    iconv('UTF-8', 'cp1251', "\nТелефон: ") . $_REQUEST['Phone'] .
    iconv('UTF-8', 'cp1251', "\nТема: ") . $_REQUEST['Subject'] .
    iconv('UTF-8', 'cp1251', "\nСообщение: ") . $_REQUEST['Message'];

  $result = mail($mail, $subject, $message, $header);
  echo "<!DOCTYPE html>";
  echo "<html><head>"; 
  echo '<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=\"UTF-8\">'; 
  echo "<title>Моба</title>"; 
  echo "</head>"; 
  echo "<body>"; 
  echo $result ? "Ваше сообщение отправлено." : "При отправке заказа возникла ошибка. Пожалуйста, попробуйте позже."; 
  echo "</body>"; 
  echo "</html>";
?>
```

Вот код формы:

```html
                    <form role="form" method="post" id="contact-form">
                        <input type="text" placeholder="Ваше имя" name="Name" id="Name" required>
                        <input type="email" placeholder="Email" name="Email" id="Email" required>
                        <input type="text" placeholder="Номер телефона" name="Phone" id="Phone">
                        <input type="text" placeholder="Тема сообщения" name="Subject" id="Subject">
                        <textarea placeholder="Сообщение" name="Message" id="Message" required></textarea>
                        <button type="submit" id="submit">Отправить</button>
                        <div id="success"></div>
                    </form>
```

Скрины того, что на выходе приложил.
Есть мысли у кого?
[image: Яндекс]
[image: Мэйл.ру]

Answer (score 1):

Так ты перекодируешь только часть информации, функция iconv. У тебя вся страница передает данные в UTF-8, потом в скрипте, часть данный преобразуешь в кириллицу, часть даных, которые будут в письме у тебя остаются в UTF-8. Вот и получается каша.

Comment: убери эту функцию либо перекодируй целиком все параметры и еще важно какая кодировка самого файла со скриптом

Comment: Понял!
Все встало на свои места.
Спасибо!

Answer (score 0):

У тебя все UTF8 потом переделываешь в cp1251 а заголовки пишешь всеровно utf8

по идее сейчас тебе нужно просто убрать все iconv. Или если хочешь отправлять по какойто причине в cp1251 то нужно

```
  $header  = "Content-type: text/plain; charset=\"UTF-8\"";
```

переписать на

```
  $header  = "Content-type: text/plain; charset=\"cp1251\"";
```